# Auto Complete de Endereços com Api Google

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

Como não tenho conhecimento de javascript Preciso de uma ajudinha....
Oque eu Preciso é fazer um autocomplete de endereços em varios campos por uma Api google  como poderia fazer isso?

Esse exemplo a baixo é oque eu precisava, mais sem a necessidade do mapa
e que posso utiliza-lo em mais de 1 campo.

Quando coloco mais de um input ele não funciona

```
   <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your   
   address"onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>

  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your 
  address"onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

 <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
 <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>




<script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
street_number: 'short_name',
route: 'long_name',
locality: 'long_name',
administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
country: 'long_name',
postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
// location types.
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
  {types: ['geocode']});

// When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
// fields in the form.
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
// Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

for (var component in componentForm) {
document.getElementById(component).value = '';
document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
}

// Get each component of the address from the place details
// and fill the corresponding field on the form.
for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
if (componentForm[addressType]) {
  var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
  document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
}
}
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var geolocation = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: geolocation,
    radius: position.coords.accuracy
  });
  autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
 });
 }
 }
 // [END region_geolocation]

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=AIzaSyDUJxq1ZeYtVmHeoMv9OdqJAB_SaddyQ9k&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Acredito que este link (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?hl=pt-br#introduction) da documentação do Google pode te ajudar.

Comment: Ola Bruno eu até tinha visto esse documentação o problema é quando coloco mais de um campo ele para de funcioanar

Comment: Desculpe, Fabio. Removi minha resposta pois a API do Google não está preparada para este tipo de implementação que pensei. Ao tentar incluir duas vezes a API uma exceção é gerada pelo interpretador Javascript. Lamento não poder ajudá-lo.